# how to remove the value from the list

Tags: java, servlet-3.0

> **Here my Code:**

```
int ii = 0;
HTMLOption[] options = new HTMLOption[zoneList.size()];
for (AuditPlanSch zone : zoneList) {
    System.out.println("Before Temp====" + tmp.getZoneCode() + "---list-" + zone.getZoneCode() + "----iii" + ii);
    if (tmp.getZoneCode().equals(zone.getZoneCode())) {
        System.out.println("Temp==2==" + tmp.getZoneCode() + "---list-2-" + zone.getZoneCode());
        zoneList.remove(zone.getZoneCode());
    }
    System.out.println("After Temp====" + tmp.getZoneCode() + "---list--" + zone.getZoneCode() + "----iii" + ii);
    options[ii++] = new HTMLOption(zone.getZoneCode(), zone.getZoneName(), false);

}
```

> **the output:**

```
Before Temp====14751---list--14751----iii1
Temp==2==14751---list-2-14751

After Temp====14751---list--14751----iii1

Before Temp====14751---list--14752----iii2

After Temp====14751---list--14752----iii2

Before Temp====14751---list--14754----iii3

After Temp====14751---list--14754----iii3

Before Temp====14751---list--14756----iii4

After Temp====14751---list--14756----iii4

Before Temp====14751---list--15844----iii5

After Temp====14751---list--15844----iii5

Before Temp====14751---list--M6205----iii6

After Temp====14751---list--M6205----iii6
```

> **the equal value not remove from the list.**

Comment: Temp==2==14751---list-2-14751

After Temp====14751---list--14751----iii1

Comment: Value is Same, But not remove from list,Temp==2==14751---list-2-14751

After Temp====14751---list--14751----iii1

Comment: First, make sure your POJO implements "equals"(note that this is the `equals` method of the parameter that will be used, so it must be a `AuditPlanSch` to work) Then, you can't remove from a `List` using a `for each` loop. You need to use an iterator.

Comment: equals() is right, it'll be execute inside of a if block.

Comment: `List.remove(Object o)` use `o.equals` method to find the first occurence, that's the part I was mentionning. I wasn't complete enough.

Comment: can't understand.  please provide the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your `zoneList` is a list of `AuditPlanSch`, but at `zoneList.remove(zone.getZoneCode());` you are trying to remove the code (which is an Integer or String I assume).

So one change is: `zoneList.remove(zone.getZoneCode());` should be `zoneList.remove(zone);`.

This will however give a ConcurrentModificationException because you are trying to remove items from the list you are for-eaching over. So, instead change it to this:

```
for(Iterator<AuditPlanSch> it = zoneList.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
  AuditPlanSch zone = it.next();
  if (tmp.getZoneCode().equals(zone.getZoneCode())) { 
    it.remove();
  }
  options[ii++] = new HTMLOption(zone.getZoneCode(), zone.getZoneName(), false);
}
```

---

EDIT: In addition, your print lines doesn't make much sense, since even though you've removed it from the list, you are still accessing the `zone` and `tmp` in the variables.

To see that the values are removed from the list as expected, try printing the entire list.

In addition, I'm suspecting you want to add `null` to the `HTMLOption` when removed, so I've added that to the code as well:

```
for(Iterator<AuditPlanSch> it = zoneList.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
  System.out.println("List before: "+zoneList);
  AuditPlanSch zone = it.next();
  String zoneCode = zone.getZoneCode();
  String zoneName = zone.getZoneName();
  if (tmp.getZoneCode().equals(zone.getZoneCode())) {
    System.out.println("Remove zone with code "+zone.getZoneCode());
    it.remove();
    zoneCode = null;
    zoneName = null;
  }
  System.out.println("List after: "+zoneList);
  options[ii++] = new HTMLOption(zoneCode, zoneName, false);
}
```

Comment: not working, it's showing error like , java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:939)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:893)

Comment: error is showing in the for loop line

Comment: and the both beans are String value only, not a Integer

Comment: @EdwinBenjamin I've modified the code, it indeed contained a mistake. `zoneList.remove(zone);` should have been `it.remove();` when using the iterator. Could you try it again to see if it now works?

Comment: @ Kevin:Still that value not remove,Before Temp====14751---list--14751----iii1
after Temp====14751---list--14751----iii1

Comment: @EdwinBenjamin That's because you are printing the item itself, not the list to see the changes. The `zone` and `tmp` are variables that remain in memory even though you've removed it from the list. I've added an _EDIT_ section which prints the entire list before and after to see it does correctly get removed from the list as expected.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are not using the correct instance type to remove for this list.

[`List.remove(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-)

> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present (optional operation). If this list does not contain the element, it is unchanged. More formally, removes the element with the lowest index i such that **(o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i)))** (if such an element exists). Returns true if this list contained the specified element (or equivalently, if this list changed as a result of the call).

So you need to pass an instance that can be compared with the instance in your list :

```
zoneList.remove(zone);
```

Second, `AuditPlanSch` must implement `equals(Object)` method. This is needed for `List.remove(Object)` to find the instance to remove. (As the documentation mentionned)

Last, you need to use an iterator to be able to update a list will iterating (or by index, but iterator is simpler) or you will get a concurrent modification exception.

---

Of course, you could go with a much simpler way, using the [`Collection.removeif`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method:

```
final tmp ...
list.removeIf(zone -> tmp.getZoneCode().equals(zone.getZoneCode()))
```

This will simple remove every instance `zone` where `tmp.getZoneCode().equals(zone.getZoneCode())` is true. Note that `tmp` must be final (or effectively final) for this lambda expression to compile.

The advantage here is that you don't have to make sur the instance implements `equals` properly, you define the condition to use.